# regular expression in address pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

```
\(Uni(t|ts)|Sho(p|ps)|Offic(e|es)|Fla(t|ts)?|Rm|Roo(m|ms)|Suit(e|es)).\w+(-|&)?\w*\gi
```

I am using the above pattern to find the matches, but there are 2 cases that the regex didn't find, how can I find "Rm. 2301" and "Flat/Room 5" in editing my regex?

use case in online editor
https://regex101.com/r/Sc1Feg/4

```
unmatched cases
Rm. 2301, Blk. B3-B4, 
Flat/Room 5, 9/F, 

matched cases
rm A, 17/F., 
Flat F, 9/F, 
Flat G1, 10/F, 
Flat C, 36/F, Block 1, 
Flat 1107&1108, 11/F, 
Flat 2301, 23/F, F
Unit 3, 2/F, L
Unit 1603 16/F 
Offices D-F, 23/F, 
Office D-F, 23/F, 
Unit 1901, 19/F, 
Units A, 6/F, 
Shop 14, G/F, 
Rooms 2202, 
Suite 702, 7/F.,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... how about something more generic, yet still specific enough, like ... [`/^[\w./]+\s+[\w&-]+/`](https://regex101.com/r/klyYjh/1) ..?

After all **there is generic pattern, two whitespace-separated character-sequences**, which can be matched as follows ...

- `^[\w./]+\s+` ... right from the start anything that matches at least either a **word** a **dot** or a **slash** character until one reaches an **including whitespace (sequence)** ...
- `[\w&-]+` ... the matching then does continuo with anything which is at least either a **word** or an **ampersand** or a **minus** character.

```js
console.log(
`Rm. 2301, Blk. B3-B4, 
Flat/Room 5, 9/F, 
rm A, 17/F., 
Flat F, 9/F, 
Flat G1, 10/F, 
Flat C, 36/F, Block 1, 
Flat 1107&1108, 11/F, 
Flat 2301, 23/F, F
Unit 3, 2/F, L
Unit 1603 16/F 
Offices D-F, 23/F, 
Office D-F, 23/F, 
Unit 1901, 19/F, 
Units A, 6/F, 
Shop 14, G/F, 
Rooms 2202, 
Suite 702, 7/F.,`.match(/^[\w./]+\s+[\w&-]+/gm));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

About the pattern

- This part `Rm. 2301, Blk. B3-B4,` does not match because the last part of the pattern that you tried has `.\w+`

  The pattern matches `Rm` in the alternation, the `.` in the pattern can also match the dot in the string but then there is a space after `Rm.`  which will not be matched by the following `\w`.
- In this part `Flat/Room 5` the space and 5 are not matched due to the same mechanism.

  `Flat` is matched in the alternation, the `.` in the pattern matches `/` and the `\w+` matches `Room`, but this part `(-|&)?\w*` in the pattern does not match the space after it.

---

As all the example strings match till before the comma, one option is to match all that follows except a comma.

It is a broader match, but it might prevent creating a more complex pattern to account for all the variations.

```
\b(?:Units?|Shops?|Offices?|Flats?|Rm|Rooms?|Suites?)[^,\r\n]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uimllL/1)

Note that you can change part like this `(p|ps)` into matching a `p` followed by an optional `s` and remove the group.

Answer (score 0):

A *perhaps* more readable regex would be this:

`/(Flat\/Room|Flat|Suite|Rooms|Rm\.|Rm|Shop|Units|Unit|Offices|Office) ([\w&-]+)/gmi`

And it catches the room type inside the 1st group and the number next to it (and before the comma) in the group 2.

Explanation:

- `(A|B|C)`: Will capture in group 1 either `A`, `B` or `C`.
- `([\w&-]+)`: Will capture in group 2 an alphanumeric or `&` or `-`, any number of times.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Sc1Feg/5

Answer (score 0):

Since `Rm. 2301` contains a period and a space, this portion of the regex will not match:

```
.\w
```

To fix it, you can use the plus operator (`+`) so that it will match the period and the space. To prevent it from expanding the capture to the end of the line, you can also use the lazy operator (`?`).

```js
.+?\w
```

So the final regex would be:

```js
/(Uni(t|ts)|Sho(p|ps)|Offic(e|es)|Fla(t|ts)?|Rm|Roo(m|ms)|Suit(e|es)).+?\w+(-|&)?\w*/
```